# Compare Two Dates in R create new column

Tags: r, date, comparison

I am trying to create a column in a dataframe that says basically if the date is greater than today then it equals 0 else equals 1:

```
Data$Date_Flag <- ifelse(Data$D1_Date > Sys.Date(),0,
                            ifelse(Data$D1_Date <= Sys.Date(),1))
```

Here is the error message I get.

```
Error in ifelse(Data$D1_Date <= Sys.Date(), 1) : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need the second ifelse. `ifelse(Data$D1_Date > Sys.Date(),0,1)`

Comment: Or just `as.integer(x <= Sys.Date())` and don't do `ifelse` at all.

Comment: Thanks, both of these solutions work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just negate the logical test:

```
Data$Date_Flag <- !(Data$D1_Date > Sys.Date() )
```